# Why My exported file (.CSV)'s numbers are wrongly represented?

Tags: r

I'm having a problem with exporting the data I want to .CSV file. it's always like this only in this exported file, the others exported files are ok. can you help me out?

I thought that the problem is from my PC language , since I'm using a German PC but R is in German and R studio is English. I tried to change both of them to the same language and it didn't work out!

Is it possible that the problem is from the language?

This how the output looks like, if you notice in the mean part, the numbers are represented in a weird way.

The results when exported to .CSV:

[image: The results when exported to .CSV]

This picture shows the same matrix but in R studio :

[image: The results inside R studio]

Comment: Is it because German excel uses `,` as `.`? Try using an argument when writing the table e.g `dec = "."`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't trust excel as it will convert the csv file when opened depending on your windows language setting. Take a look at the csv with a text editor and if the csv is fine (which I would guess) simply change your windows system language to "English (USA)", close **all** excel instances and then open the csv. I'm on a german PC too and have always the same problem.

Comment: thank you man.  you are right man , i checked it on Texteditor and it did work!

Answer (score 0):

I am not a R user, but it seems to be a locale problem. Try to use`Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL","English")`

Answer (score 0):

The problem are the thousands separator in Excel.

1. So the simpelst way would be to deactivate it in excel.
2. Within R you can do import the data as character (`stringsAsFactors = F`) and manually replace each `.` with `""` and then each `,` with `.`. Mention that `.` as a pattern as a special meaning (`?regex`). That's why we have to mark it as a normal dot with `\\.` when looking for it as a simple dot.

I saved a file with `.` as thousand separator and `,` as decimal separator as `Test.csv`.

```
csv <- read.csv2("Test.csv", header = F, stringsAsFactors = F)
#              V1
#1  15.123.515,00 ## <- these are characters/strings, not numbers
#2  15.241.241,00
#3   1.251.636,00
#4  46.345.325,00
#5 343.434.536,00
apply(csv, 2, function(x) as.numeric(gsub(",",".",gsub("\\.", "", x))))
#             V1
# [1,]  15123515 ## <- these are numeric/numbers now
# [2,]  15241241
# [3,]   1251636
# [4,]  46345325
# [5,] 343434536
```

With the `apply` and parameter `2` I apply the replacing (`gsub`) on every column. If you have just a few columns you can change them individually without using `apply`.

Comment: thanks a lot for the helpful reply but this is i think for importing. my problem is with exporting. thanks a million